# Border with :before

Tags: css

[image]

```
.box{
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 280px;
background: green
}
  .box:before{
    content: '';
    border: 5px solid pink;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

Tried to make the box with border in the blank gap between box and border. I tried both border in box or :before but the borders are not showing outside the box along with white space.

Appreciate help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not sure"? It's either correct or not correct, and it's not difficult to find out for yourself.

Comment: @BoltClock - I have tested it but it is not appearing as it is supposed to show. thats why i am not sure why it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: When you say "supposed" you are implying you think it should look different. Good idea to show what you want to end up with, so we can explain why the code you used to get that effect isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it is to use the following CSS:

```
#box{
     position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    padding:0px;
    background:#fff;
    border:12px solid #390;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#box:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1; top:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px; 
    bottom:2px;
    background-color: pink
}
```

**See the DEMO here**: http://jsfiddle.net/fvHJq/1/

Comment: thanks! we need to have positioning? can it go without positioning? just wonder.

Comment: No unfortunately this is the best you can do :/

Comment: But it's quite convenient to use :)

Comment: thanks and i tried to fiddle with your code to make mine work, but unfortunately it is not :( the background is white on my local and then border is white. the box will be on the background image.

Comment: @joe What do you exactly want?

Comment: there will be background image then have a box on top of that background image. So the box will have border outside with a gap between image and box just like the image i drew above

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, a simple `outline` might help:

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #1baaaa;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    outline: 5px solid #ff7474;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KBQ3/)

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it does not appear. the background is white on my local and then border is white. the box will be on the background image.